# Reg Ex to match a ? or the Unicode %3d

Tags: regex

I have an expression which matches the question mark in a url query string and I find myself  needing to extend the expression to accommodate for a case where the URL I am trying to read contains the unicode equivalent of the question mark %3d

the expression is

```
var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
```

From what very little I know of RegEx I thought this might work

```
var regexS = "[\\?&]|[\\%3d&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: If the url contains `%3d`, (normally) it shouldn't be interpreted as a query delimiter. That's why it's escaped.

Comment: note that `%3d` means `=`. `&` is `%3f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Javascript for the purposes of string escaping.

In `"[\\?&]|[\\%3d&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"` note that

- concatenation (`abc`) has priority over alternation (`a|b|c`) and
- `[\\%3d&]` means "percent or 3 or d or ampersand" (character class).
- The escaped form of `?` is %3F, not %3D. %3D means `=`. See [wikipedia: percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_escape#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters)
- the ampersand in the first character class is present to match `&q2=` in `www.example.com?q1=v1&q2=v2`. Perhaps you want to allow escaped ampersand as well. Its escaped form is %26

You probably mean `"([\\?&]|\\%3f|\\%26)" + name + "=([^&#]*)"` instead.

Also note that `?` has no special meaning inside a character class and doesn't need to be escaped: `"([?&]|%3f|%26)" + name + "=([^&#]*)"`

Comment: Thanks for the response. people who understand regEx never cease to amaze me. I am usinghttp://www.nvcc.edu/home/drodgers/ceu/resources/test_regexp.asp to test the expression and using ([?&]|\\%3d&) to test www.mydomain.com?q=123 tests true but www.mydomain.com%3dq=123 tests false.

Comment: good eye on the %3f I was looking at the wrong part of the query string. Thanks for the help it worked!